# VHDL Counter does not update when desired

Tags: vhdl, counter

For a project I am working on, I require a counter whose value increases as soon as the increment control goes high (i.e. on the rising edge). However, I have had trouble implementing this in VHDL.

Here is some code that I have written:

```
IF Reset='1' THEN
        count := 0; -- Asynchronous reset
    ELSIF rising_edge(clock) THEN
        IF Enable = '1' THEN
            count := count+1; -- Increment
        END IF;
    END IF;
    q <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(count,12));
```

Here is the ModelSim simulation waveform:
[image]

As you can see, 'q' is only updated one clock cycle AFTER the Enable input goes high. I want q to increment as soon as Enable goes high. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is fine, when rising edge appears, the signal must be stable, not rising by itself. You will encounter this k7nd of problem later, when the logic you build will not propagate the signal fast enough and the output will not be ready before your next clock.

So foe now in modelsim make "enable" stable somewhere in the middle of your previous clock cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Gregory's answer: if `Enable` is a synchronous signal (that is, it is produced with the same clock signal `clock`), then when `clock` rises `enable` is still low (even though this is hard to see in Modelsim).

This is not really a problem, just something you need to account for in your design.